# 2010 Block Group Income

Tags: united-states, census, demography

Does anyone know why there isn't 2010 income data at the block group level on American Fact Finder?

I don't see it at the census tract either. Looking for documentation explaining why it's not there or instructions on how to get the data on American Fact Finder or elsewhere.

Comment: If this is open data then I think this question should be researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

I dont believe block group data were added to the online tool until the 2009-2013 american Community Survey (ACS) 5-year estimates. For 2010 data, I assume you want the 2006-2010 ACS 5-year estimates. The 2010 Decennial Census did not ask questions about income, thus you need to get the data from the 2006-10 ACS 5-year estimates.

To get the income data at block group level, you will need to use the Summary Files. See the documentation on the Census website here:
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/technical-documentation/summary-file-documentation.2010.html

If you only need the one data table you can use the Excel lookup tool they have. Or, better yet, check out the IPUMS  National Historical Geographic Information System (NHGIS) project where you can get the data for any year plus associated GIS files here:
https://www.nhgis.org/